# There always is a dbus error at startup

Tags: dbus

Does anyone know what it is? I hope that I can get rid off it.
[image]

Comment: Just to confirm that I have this also; I did not bother to investigate nor report a bug on launchpad.net.  I send a report every time. I just hope that seeing the number of bug report they might try to do somthing. But I don't have high hope on this.

Comment: To add insult to injurie, When you look at the crash in `/var/crash`, one can see a line like `UnreportableReason: Invalid core dump: BFD:.[...]`. So there is another bug in the ubg reporting tool. So the dev might never see the bug report after all

Comment: I have opened a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/1807709. Fill free to add yourself to the affected people.

Comment: By the way, I'm on Xorg.